# 'Undefined reference to symbol -glEnable' when compiling ftgl

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, compiling

A software that I need to use requires the library ftgl [FTGL download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ftgl/) and I am trying to build this from source. The version is ftgl 2.1.3 rc5 and I am trying to build this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Can somebody let me know what is the missing library that I must install under /usr/local/lib in order to fix the missing reference error?

These are the errors I get

```
Making all in demo
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/w/m/ftgl-2.1.3~rc5/demo'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -I/usr/local/include   /freetype2 -I/usr/local/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -L/usr/local/lib -lfreetype -lglut  -o simple simple-simple.o  ../src/libftgl.la 

g++ -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -o .libs/simple simple-simple.o  -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.so -lglut ../src/.libs/libftgl.so 
/usr/bin/ld: simple-simple.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glEnable'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 Makefile:327: recipe for target 'simple' failed
 make[2]: *** [simple] Error 1
 make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/w/m/ftgl-2.1.3~rc5/demo'
 Makefile:338: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
 make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/w/m/ftgl-2.1.3~rc5'
Makefile:249: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Why you are trying to install it from source? It is available in official `ftgl-dev` package in [xenial/universe](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&searchon=names&keywords=ftgl-dev).

Comment: @N0rbert - I was trying to do what the downstream software was requesting.  I am trying to compile VAPOR - https://www.vapor.ucar.edu/internal/downloads/source-distributions and the version required is the one I listed in the question.

Comment: There is ftgl 2.1.3~rc5-4+nmu1 in official repository. Does it fit your needs?

Comment: Simply by `sudo apt-get install ftgl-dev`.

Comment: @N0rbert - Ok thanks. Out of curiosity do you have any idea what is -glEnable ? Is it OpenGL ?

Comment: No, I do not know -glEnable. Try to follow their [official guide](https://www.vapor.ucar.edu/docs/vapor-installation/vapor-source-installation). You can find correct names of dependent packages with https://packages.ubuntu.com/ (use search for package names and contents), then install them with `apt-get`. Do not forget to enable deb-src in your sources.list.